# Loading in a set of images with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of images in jquery that I am attempting to load into a series of divs when the user clicks a specific box. On my localhost everything works great, but when I put on the internets. Something really odd happens.

[image]

the url that I am attempting to load is split into each individual character and separate div is created for each letter...?

here is the code that is used to create the div's and sign a background image to all of them.

```
            for (var i = 0, len = images[index].length; i < len; i++){
            $('#project_display #slides .slides_container').append($('<div></div>'))
            $('#project_display #slides .slides_container div').eq(i).css('background','url(' + images[index][i] +') center center no-repeat');
        }
```

images contains arrays of other images.
any help would be so great!

thanks!

**UPDATE**

here is images and another array creation:

`
var circus = new Array();
    circus[0] = 'images/projects/circus1.jpg';
    circus[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU9aA.png) = 'images/projects/circus2.jpg';
    circus[2] = 'images/projects/circus3.jpg';
    circus[3] = 'images/projects/circus4.jpg';
    circus[4] = 'images/projects/circus5.jpg';

var images = new Array();
    images[0] = 'images/projects/radioshack_899.jpg';
    images[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU9aA.png) = radioImages;
    images[2] = dwarf;
    images[3] = dwarf;
    images[4] = circus;
`

Comment: Holy crap, where did I put those glasses again ?

Comment: What is the structure of `images`?

Comment: `images` looks like an array of strings. `images[index][i]` is then equivalent to `images[index].charAt(i)`.

Comment: so images is an array of arrays and I'm thinking that I'm doing something really wrong when I try to look through it. `images[index][i]`

Comment: `images` is definitely an Array of strings and the `for` appends the characters individually to a `div`. The problem is not in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell without seeing more, but you are either doing something wrong in the for loop, or you are doing something wrong in the `url(' + images[index][i] +')`.

Are you sure you that `images.length` is'nt what your looking for in the for loop, and something tells me you should remove the `[i]` in the url(), like so: `url(' + images[index] +')`

Maybe it should be something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    $('<div></div>').css('background','url(' + images[i] +') center center no-repeat')
       .appendTo($('#project_display #slides .slides_container'));
}
```

And you should try to shorten down those selectors if possible.

Comment: well im almost positive your right about `url(' + images[index][i] +')` being the problem. The thing is images[index] should return an array of images, which i was then using `[i]` to select from. but maybe my syntax is off?

Comment: @JamesDunay - if your update above is correct, that is just a regular array, not an array inside an array, so [index] will select one of the string values in that array, and [i] will select a character in that string, like Rob W says in the comments above. - You probably need to check the length of just the array `images.length` in the for loop, and then remove the [index] part of your url(), and keep the [i] to select images based on iteration.